# Is there a Python-accessible API on the Mac for accessing and manipulating email in Mail.app?

Tags: python, objective-c, macos

I want to write programs that manipulate email in my Gmail account, which is synched to my Mac. I can access using Gmail's IMAP interface, but it is *slow* (I have over 180,000 email messages). I can pursue multi-threaded access, but it would make more sense to just run my code on the local copy. Is there an API that I can access from python and, if so, where is it documented?

The specific thing I want to do is to remove all of the duplicate email messages that Mail.app creates in the mailbox when drafts is stored on gmail.

Comment: What kinds of manipulation do you want to do? Is it very complex stuff, or just things like bulk filtering/moving, etc.?

Comment: Hi @AndrewMadsen: I want to remove gmail dups; I've updated the question to indicate this.

Comment: I don't know of a true API (let alone a Python one) for doing what you're talking about. You can use AppleScript or JavaScript for Automation (which use the same underlying interface into the app) to do it. There are ways to use Python to script using these interfaces as well, but there's a fair bit of impedance there, and I'd recommend just using actual AppleScript or JavaScript instead. That said, if speed is your main concern, these are likely to be disappointing. AppleScript is great, but it's not known for its performance.